# How to return a nested object's property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, return

I'm studying JavaScript online and the module wants me to use dot notation to return the value of an object's property which is nested within another object: specifically *salesAssociate.contactInfo.email*

Ok. Simple enough concept which I have done successfully in Python, but when I try it below I get an 'undefined' message. There aren't any clarifying points in the module on how to return the desired value and I've tried which feels like everything.

```
const salesAssociate = () => {
    const mike = {
        name: "Mike",
        location: "Milwaukee",
        contactInfo: {
            phone: "343-343-3434",
            email: "mike_wiz@aol.com"
        }
    }
    
    
    // Return the email address of the sales associate
    return 
}
```

on the *return* line I've tried

```
return salesAssociate.contactInfo.email
```

I've also tried wrapping it in console.log(). I've even first set it as a const and tried to return the const. Like I said, the module is not giving any hints in how return operates and I'm finding the instructions and explanations on how it works unclear.

Comment: `salesAssociate` is a function so it needs to be called. Also The function doesn't return anything. Consider returning `mike`?

Comment: You need to write: `return mike.contactInfo.email`. See: [MDN - return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)